# Change icon on button in scout eclipse

Tags: image, button, toggle, eclipse-scout

I would like to implement some think like toggle button in scout eclipse. 
What I need is to change image of button for state.

I see function

```
setIconId(String)
```

but I dont know how to find parameter for this function. How to find image that scout use for different state of button?

Marko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### setIconId(..) and Icons

It is a good practice in your Scout Application to pass as Argument from `setIconId(..)` a constant defined in the `Icons` Class. See [Icons page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Icons) on the wiki.

An example for your use case:

```
setIconId(Icons.WeatherSun)
```

In the [Demo Widget Application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Demo#Widgets) there is an [Icons class](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.shared/src/org/eclipsescout/demo/widgets/shared/Icons.java):

```
org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.shared.Icons
```

Here some constants defined in this class:

```
public static final String WeatherRain = "weather_rain";
public static final String WeatherSnow = "weather_snow";
public static final String WeatherSun = "weather_sun";
```

The values defined in the constants represent an identifier for the image.

The Image lookup is realized by the [ImageLocator](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Icon_Locator). (Depending on the UI technology, the appropriate IconLocator will be used. For example, in case of Swing the `SwingIconLocator` implementation).

In case of `weather_sun` the default implementation of the ImageLocator will look for a File called `weather_sun.<ext>` (where `<ext>` can be `gif`, `png` and so on) in the `\resources\icons\` folder of each plugins. In this case it will find the File: [\org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.client\resources\icons\weather_sun.png](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.client/resources/icons/weather_sun.png)

If the image is not found, you will see a log entry like this:

```
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.swing.SwingIconLocator.warnImageNotFound(SwingIconLocator.java:141) could not find image 'weather_sun'
```

In the Scout SDK, there is an [Icons Editor](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/SDK/Icons_Editor). This Editor represents all the constants defined in the `Icons` class and the corresponding Icon. Is a file not found a red square is displayed instead of the image.

---

### Toggle Button

There is no specific field for Toggle Button, use an `AbstractButton` an set the display style to `DISPLAY_STYLE_TOGGLE`.

See also:

- [10.8 - Buttons and Links](http://tools.bsiag.com/scoutbook/4.0/2014-07-11_10-05-26/html/bookch11.html#x88-13700010.8) in the Scout Boook.
- [ToggleButton wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/ToggleButton).

---

### Changing the icon in a Toogle Button

I think this code snippet does what you are looking for:

```
@Order(10)
public class ToggleButton1 extends AbstractButton {
  @Override
  protected boolean getConfiguredProcessButton() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected void execClickAction() throws ProcessingException {
    if (isSelected()) {
      setIconId(Icons.WeatherSun);
    }
    else {
      setIconId(Icons.WeatherRain);
    }
  }
}
```

It would also be possible (and even better) to use `execToggleAction` instead of `execClickAction`.

Screenshot:

[image: Eclipse Scout - Toogle Button with Icon - Swing UI]

Comment: Hi, I figure it out how to change icons, but I still don't know how you achieved this "toggle" gray look of button

Comment: I have extended my answer. You should check the wiki or the scout book. Toogle buttons are explained.